# Right way to give Service Principals access to ADLS files

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, service-principal

We have an Azure Datalake Store with a lot of directories and files in it. Now we want to give access to a subset of these files to a growing list of service principals. Because it would take very long to add each service principal on its own, we would like to use a different/bundled approach. What is the best way to do this in Azure?
Using groups, roles or permissions for example?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an `Azure AD security group` in `Azure Active Directory` -> `Groups` -> `New Group`, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-groups-create-azure-portal), then add it in the `Access` of your ADLS file with the permissions you need.

Then if you want to give the permissions to the new service principal, just add it in the `Members` -> `Add members` of the group.

For more details, you could refer to [**Securing data stored in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-secure-data).